# where are my .d.ts files if I run "typings install react --global"?

Tags: typescript-typings

I know where they are when I run "typings install --global --save react", but where they are by "typings install --global react"?

Are they stored in the global node-modules folder?

But I just can't find them there.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a typings directory in your project root. If you install a global declaration file, it will be installed in typings/global/react/index.d.ts.